# Implementation of IContextMenu COM interface using JNA

Tags: java, winapi, com, jna, vtable

I need all items from Windows Explorer Shell Menu. I am implementing with jna the IShellFolder COM object interface. But now I have a problem with implementation the interface IContextMenu for query the context menu. When I invoke the QueryContextMenu function the result of HResult is 0 like true, but the HMenu has been empty when I invoke function GetMenuItemCount and the result is 0.

So can you tell me where I have a bug. Thank you very much.

This is my code for IContextMenu:

```
public interface IContextMenu {
Guid.IID IID_IContextMenu = new Guid.IID("{000214E4-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");

WinNT.HRESULT QueryContextMenu(WinDef.HMENU hMenu, int indexMenu, int idCmdFirst, int idCmdLast, int uFlags);
WinNT.HRESULT InvokeCommand(Pointer pici);
WinNT.HRESULT GetCommandString(IntByReference idCmd, int uType, IntByReference pReserved, WTypes.LPSTR pszName, int cchMax);

public static class Converter {
    public Converter() {
    }

    public static IContextMenu PointerToIContextMenu(PointerByReference ptr) {
        final Pointer interfacePointer = ptr.getValue();
        final Pointer vTablePointer = interfacePointer.getPointer(0);
        final Pointer[] vTable = new Pointer[3];
        vTablePointer.read(0, vTable, 0, 3);

        return new IContextMenu() {
            @Override
            public WinNT.HRESULT QueryContextMenu(WinDef.HMENU hMenu, int indexMenu, int idCmdFirst, int idCmdLast, int uFlags) {
                Function f = Function.getFunction(vTable[2], Function.ALT_CONVENTION);
                return new WinNT.HRESULT(f.invokeInt(new Object[] { interfacePointer, hMenu.getPointer(), indexMenu, idCmdFirst, idCmdLast, uFlags }));
            }

            @Override
            public WinNT.HRESULT InvokeCommand(Pointer pici) {
                Function f = Function.getFunction(vTable[1], Function.ALT_CONVENTION);
                return new WinNT.HRESULT(f.invokeInt(new Object[]{ interfacePointer, pici }));
            }

            @Override
            public WinNT.HRESULT GetCommandString(IntByReference idCmd, int uType, IntByReference pReserved, WTypes.LPSTR pszName, int cchMax) {
                Function f = Function.getFunction(vTable[0], Function.ALT_CONVENTION);
                return new WinNT.HRESULT(f.invokeInt(new Object[] { interfacePointer, idCmd, uType, pReserved, pszName, cchMax }));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

}

And this is my code to invoke the QueryContextMenu:

```
IContextMenu contextMenu = null;
PointerByReference contextMenuPtr = new PointerByReference();
Pointer ppidlsPointer = new Memory(Native.POINTER_SIZE * ppidls.length);
ppidlsPointer.setPointer(0, ppidls[0].getValue());
hResult = psfParentFolder.GetUIObjectOf(null, 1, ppidls[0].getPointer(), new Guid.REFIID(IContextMenu.IID_IContextMenu), new IntByReference(0), contextMenuPtr);
if (!COMUtils.SUCCEEDED(hResult))
   return false;

/* End Section */

/* Begin Get Context Menu Section */

contextMenu = IContextMenu.Converter.PointerToIContextMenu(contextMenuPtr);
WinDef.HMENU hMenu = User32Ex.INSTANCE.CreatePopupMenu();
hResult = contextMenu.QueryContextMenu(hMenu, 0, 1, 30, 0x00000004);
if (!COMUtils.SUCCEEDED(hResult)) {
   int error = Native.getLastError();
   return false;
}

int count = User32Ex.INSTANCE.GetMenuItemCount(hMenu.getPointer());
if (count > 0) {
}

/* End Section */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be reading what you think from the `IContextMenuVtbl`.  This code indicates you're only collecting 3 function pointers:

```
final Pointer[] vTable = new Pointer[3];
vTablePointer.read(0, vTable, 0, 3);
```

However, this interface (as most COM interfaces) extends `IUnknown`, so automatically gets the methods `QueryInterface` at index 0, `AddRef` at index 1, and `Release` at index 2.  So those are the three methods you appear to be calling, although with the wrong arguments.

From [the header file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/deps/perl/+/master/c/i686-w64-mingw32/include/shobjidl.h#1925), the pointer indices continue:

- 3: `QueryContextMenu`
- 4: `InvokeCommand`
- 5: `GetCommandString`

You can either read in all 6 function pointers and reference the last 3, or attempt to read at an offset of 3 pointers using your existing numbering (but in reverse order!)

I believe you should also add an `extends IUnknown` to your interface definition.